# How to move and shrink image when sliding div in?

Tags: image, html, sliding

ive attached an image that illustrates my purpose.
http://postimage.org/image/9cmg2z8vv/

by default id like to have a big landscape or portrait image that is centered in the middle of the page. on click at the image a div should slide in from the right. the div should push the big image from center to left 50% of the screen, the big image should shrink to fit into the left 50% of the screen.

do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you need it animated?

Comment: yes this would be nice

Comment: Would CSS3 be ok, or must it be javascript?

Comment: CSS3 is fine, but it should work in safari on iOS 6.0 or above - ipad

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude javascript version. Not the best, but gets you started. I can't see your HTML, so I don't know what divs are inside other divs, but you can essentially do the same thing with transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/jMwWK/1/

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="holder">
        <div id="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slider"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#slider').animate({left: '-200px'});
        $('#holder').animate({width: '50%'});
    },1000);
});
```